# How to pass angularjs scope variable value as FormName to ng-click param and get FormName.$valid and FormName.$dirty view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I pass a scope variable as *FormName* of `ng-click` parameter to get `FormName.$valid` and `FormName.$dirty` in view *angularjs*.

Example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Main', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.FormName = 'FormNameValidation';
    $scope.showFormValidation = function(statusValid, statusDirty) {
      console.log(statusValid, statusDirty);
      $scope.FormNameValidationStatus = statusValid;
      $scope.FormNameDirtyStatus = statusDirty;
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
  <form name="MainFormName" novalidate>
    <button type="button" ng-click="showFormValidation(FormName.$valid, FormName.$dirty)">Click</button>
    <form name="FormNameValidation" novalidate>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : FormNameValidation.type.$invalid  }">
          <label class="col-sm-4 red" for="form-field-1-1">Type</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : type.$invalid  }">
            <select convert-number ng-required=&#39;true&#39; class="form-control" id="type" name="type" ng-model="Type" ng-disabled="1 == 0">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="1">A</option>
              <option value="2">B</option>
            </select>
            <p ng-show="FormNameValidation.inctype.$error.required" class="help-block col-xs-12 col-sm-reset inline">Type is Required</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      {{FormNameValidationStatus}} {{FormNameDirtyStatus}}
    </form>
  </div>
```

Output:

> undefined undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues ...

First, HTML5 does not support nested form elements but angular does with using the ng-form directive.

```
<form name="FormNameValidation" novalidate></form>
```

becomes

```
<ng-form name="FormNameValidation" novalidate></ng-form>
```

Second, you can simply name your form in your markup.

```
<form name="MainFormName" novalidate>
```

becomes

```
<form name="FormName" novalidate>
```

Which simplifies your controller function to:

```
$scope.showFormValidation = function(statusValid, statusDirty) {
   $scope.FormNameValidationStatus = statusValid;
   $scope.FormNameDirtyStatus = statusDirty;
};
```

You also had mismatched open/close tags in your HTML.

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/qDUTHW9jBE3pYYjIqIgb?p=preview)

Comment: As you mention in the second form change from "MainFormName" to "FormName". Can't we achieve my request without do the Second form change?

Comment: You can by changing <form name="MainFormName" novalidate>
 to <ng-form name="{{FormName}}" novalidate> but then ng-click="showFormValidation(FormName.$valid, FormName.$dirty)"> won't work.  Instead you'd have to pass $event in as an argument which would could be used to get the form element in your function using jQuery but that is an ugly approach in my opinion.